# Typical lag time for PayPal "Instant" Payment Notifications (IPN)?

Tags: paypal

The PayPal developer docs state that "[Instant Payment Notification](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/)  (IPN) notifies merchants ***almost*** instantly about transaction events..." (emphasis mine).

Elsewhere, their docs state that when using [Payment Data Transfer](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNPDTAnAlternativetoIPN/), "your site is notified ***immediately*** when a customer completes payment. With IPN, however, there is a material lag between the time a customer completes payment and the time your site receives notification of this event" (emphasis theirs).

Can anyone quantify how "material" IPN's "material lag" might be in a typical, non-pathological case, i.e., IPN-listener server up and running normally, and reachable from IPN sender? How far from "instantly" might "almost" instantly be?

Are we talking seconds? Minutes? More?

*Looking for actual experience in practice here, not conjecture or theory.* Thanks.

---

Some context for this question is given in [this other question over here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40426194/1337498). The use case presented there *could* in fact tolerate a few minutes of lag time between the user's requesting an instance of the service and the service delivering the answer, since the user needs to interactively answer a series of questions to provide the input required for computing the answer.

In the context of the simple approach proposed in that question (Payouts + IPN),  PDT isn't helpful, since (again, per PayPal's docs): "IPN ... sends many types of notifications, while PDT sends *just order confirmations*" (emphasis mine) -- and a payout isn't the same thing as an order confirmation.

But if the lag time for an IPN message reporting a payout could (in a non-pathological case) exceed, say, five minutes, then there might be an argument for going to the extra trouble of having the partner site place an order, and then subsequently do the order confirmation (even though it's a machine-to-machine relationship and there'd be no order or confirm "pages" or "buttons", just HTTP requests/responses).

Thoughts?

Comment: Hi, I guess there is no real answer to that question. Since the lag time depends on how far you are away from the internet node which connects to a paypal server. Actually it should take only several minutes to get an answer from such a company like paypal. But there are situations where your request answer will take longer.

Comment: Wow, really? **Minutes'** worth of _network latency_ feels more like a "pathological" case than a "typical" one. From California I usually get round-trip times of < 100ms to Amazon AWS servers on the opposite coast of North America, and just now `ping`ed yandex.ru for a minute, with no round-trip exceeding 316ms. Now, I could (possibly) imagine that PayPal's computing infrastructure might take minutes to process a payout and generate an IPN notification -- but that delay wouldn't be a function of my IPN listener's distance from PayPal's servers.

Comment: don't forget that there are some verification processes. I think it is normal because paypal itself need again some response from a bank for example. Between few seconds and 10minutes everything is fine I guess. You could do some sort of research and ask online reseller who use paypal.

Comment: Well, okay -- but wouldn't the "immediate" PDT notification be subject to the same verification requirements? It seems like the IPN lag time would have to be measured from the point at which the PDT notification **could** legitimately be delivered, not before. (And anyway, notice that I'm considering the case of a "payout", which necessarily comes out of the payer's PayPal account, and shouldn't require any external verification.)

Comment: Now I'm interested too. Voted up your question. Hopefully someone will know an answer.